# Where can I find an ATM in Luang Prabang International Airport?

Tags: airports, laos, atms

Where can I find an ATM in Luang Prabang International Airport?

I find ATMs the cheapest and most effective way (generally) of obtaining local currency when arriving in a new country but Luang Prabang International Airport doesn't seem to have put up a map of itself with this information.

Comment: Luang Prabang airport is not that big, so not much need for a map.

Comment: I saw this question in the "related" list, and the first thing I thought of was a particular anti-war song...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BCEL has an ATM outside the airport arrivals area.

Look for the "LDB Exchange" counter adjacent to the main exit. (If you stand at the counter and look out the window you'll see the sign for the ATM.)

Head outside.